# Best way to retrieve many aggregate counts from a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, report

I have a dataframe that I need to retrieve many metrics from. Dataframe columns are the following:

```
Consumer_ID|Client|Campaign|Date
```

I am trying to get the unique count of the consumer_ID column for various combinations of the Client, Campaign, and Date columns. So far I have come up with two solutions:

1. Groupby statements with count as the agg function for every combination of client, campaign, and date.
2. Writing for loops and filtering on every combination of the client, campaign and date columns and then using the nunique() function to get the final count.

My question: is there a cleaner more Pythonic way of getting the unique count of one column for all available combinations of other columns?

Example (annoying) solution using groupbys:
    Yes understood, but is there a more pythonic way to get every combination of the groupby columns? For example, right now to get all combinations I'd have to write:

```
df.groupby(['Client']).Consumer_ID.nunique()
df.groupby(['Client', 'Campaign']).Consumer_ID.nunique()
df.groupby(['Client', 'Campaign', 'Date']).Consumer_ID.nunique()
df.groupby(['Client', 'Date'].Consumer_ID.nunique()
```

Comment: Could you please post sample _input_ and _output_ data sets (5-7 rows in CSV/dict/JSON/Python code format __as text__, so one could use it when coding) and describe what do you want to do with the input data in order to get output data set? [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @MaxU Apologies, I can see how it's confusing. Solved my own question and answered it below if you're interested!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly:

```
df.groupby(df.columns.drop(Consumer_ID).tolist(), as_index=False).nunique()
```

Comment: I will try this, I'm not sure it is grouping by every single combination of columns. Edit to explain this contained in the question above.

Comment: I've a bit different case but I tried to adopt your solution and now it works just fine for me, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you're looking for is:

```
df.groupby(['Client', 'Campaign', 'Date']).Consumer_ID.nunique()
```

Comment: Yes understood, but is there a more pythonic way to get every combination of the groupby columns? For example, right now to get all combinations I'd have to write:

df.groupby(['Client']).Consumer_ID.nunique()
df.groupby(['Client', 'Campaign']).Consumer_ID.nunique()
df.groupby(['Client', 'Campaign', 'Date']).Consumer_ID.nunique()
df.groupby(['Client', 'Date'].Consumer_ID.nunique()

Comment: What kind of Data structure would you store this in? Perhaps you can provide a sample output? My initial thoughts are that you aren't going to do a lot better than 4 lines. If your challenge is scaling this up to n columns, then you could write the groupby inside a combinatorial loop but I'd want to see what you want your output to look like.

Comment: Apologies, I can see how my question was confusing. I figured out the answer and posted above if interested!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a pivot table, as below:

import pandas as pd
pd.pivot_table(df, index=['Client', 'Campaign', 'Date'], values = 'Consumer_ID', aggfunc=pd.Series.nunique)

Answer (score 0):

Answered my own question. I used itertools combinations to create all possible combinations of columns that are then used to complete all groupby aggregations. Example code below:

```
from itertools import combinations
cols = df.columns
combinations = [j for i in range(len(cols)) for j in combinations(cols, i+1)]
```

I can then use the different combinations of columns within the "combinations" list to complete all groupby aggregations without having to write the groupby statement multiple times.

Thanks!